# Retrofit2 onFailure not called for error 401

Tags: android, callback, retrofit2

I'm making a network call to login to a service, and if you pass an invalid login, the Call object from retrofit2 still calls `onResponse` but never `onFailure`.

Even in `onResponse` I can call `response.code()` and the returning code is 401, as expected.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code for the activity that starts everything:

```
Call<Login> call = LoginUtils.loginUser(ServiceUtils.getRequestHeaders(LoginActivity.this),
        BuildConfig.ORDER_SERVICE_DOMAIN, uname, pass);
call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Login>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, retrofit2.Response<Login> response) {
        System.out.println("onResponse");
        System.out.println("responseCode = " + response.code());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onFailure");

    }
});
```

Here's how we're setting up the Service layer:

```
public LoginService(final String domain, final Map<String, String> headers) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request.Builder request = original.newBuilder();
                    if (!headers.isEmpty()) {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                            request.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    request.method(original.method(), original.body());
                    return chain.proceed(request.build());
                }
            })
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    // create the rest adapter
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GSON))
            .baseUrl(domain)
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();

    loginServices = retrofit.create(LoginServices.class);
}
```

And finally, here's our interface:

```
@GET
Call<Login> getLoginCustompath(@Url String url,
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

What am I not seeing here?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `401 code` means "`Unautorized`", there is no error in the comunication and that is why `onFaliure` was not called.

The server is responding you that your user or password are wrong.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh. That's lame. I would assume an invalid login is a failure, but I was wondering if failure was reserved for network failures only. Thanks

Comment: Could be a bug on the server too.

Answer (score 3):

From Retrofit2's source code:

```
/**
   * Invoked when a network exception occurred talking to the server or when an unexpected
   * exception occurred creating the request or processing the response.
   */
  void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t);
```

`HTTP 401` means `Unauthorized` so you had a valid request with invalid credentials.

Reference: [Retrofit2 Source code](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/6b2bb3ad958e003488b8308df7927555a2b1008b/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Callback.java)